# Flip group of paths over the left group edge

Tags: svg, path, sketch-app

Maybe there is a better way to achieve this result but...

I've design the following picture by adding paths and overlying them. Now I want to flip it to get the full picture but I'm not able to do it.

[image]

Getting this result:

[image]

I tried by union the path group but I'm getting the following results (maybe because there are open paths?)

[image]

Flatten tool appears disabled. How can I merge both sides into one full picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group all your objects, including the face etc. duplicate then flip it.